# Collision on one side only in cocos2d / box2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, collision-detection

I am working on an application using cocos2d and box2d within iOS/xcode.

I have a moving sprite and some square boxes, and I can detect collisions no problem, and that is working fine.

I need to check for collision on one side of the target only, though, and have different behavioura based on which side of the target the sprite hits.

Think of it like a box with 3 closed sides and one open - if the sprite hits either of the three closed side then it should fail / die, but if it collides with the "open" edge of the target, then it should fall in.

So I need to be able to tell the difference between a collision on one side over a collision on the other, and not just check for any collision.

Any thoughts / advice?

Comment: you can attach another thin box(like line) via wield joint to one side of Your box and give it a user data then check collision

Comment: What Singhak said, except you don't need a weld joint and separate bodies, you can just put more fixtures onto the original body.

Comment: I was thinking about doing as Singhak's suggestion - creating two separate bodies, one large one that covers three sides of a smaller one. Can you expand on your suggestion of "you can just put more fixtures onto the original body"?

Comment: @Richard iforce2d want to say that you can create another fixture and add to the same body. Since a Body can have different type of fixture

Comment: Agree with @iforce2d on this.  Weld joints "flex" per the manual.  You are looking for a fixture.  Mark it as a sensor and give it userdata so you can distinguish it during the pre-solve phase in your contact listener.

Answer (score 0):

You know the BoundingBox of box. Assume, that it is allowed to cross only from left side of box.

```c
CGPoint p1; // touch previous position
CGPoint p2; // touch current position
CGRect r = box.boundingBox;
CGPoint A = r.origin;
CGPoint B = ccpAdd(A, ccp(0.f, r.size.height));

// we have the straight line AB
// if p1 is on the left side of AB and
// p2 is on the right side of AB
// then path is allowed
//
// d1 is side indicator of p1
// d2 is side indicator of p2
// if di < 0, then pi is on the left side of AB
// if di == 0, then pi is on AB
// if di > 0, then pi is on the right side of AB
// if the line is horizontal, di < 0 if the point is above the line

float d1 = (p1.x - A.x) * (B.y - A.y) - (B.x - A.x) * (p1.y - A.y)
float d2 = (p2.x - A.x) * (B.y - A.y) - (B.x - A.x) * (p2.y - A.y)

BOOL isAllowed = d1 < 0 && d2 > 0; // you can use >= and <=
```

Hope this will help you.

P. S. this solution is great if the box is not rotated. If rotated - you need to calculate A and B points using something like

```c
/** Rotates a point counter clockwise by the angle around a pivot
 @param v is the point to rotate
 @param pivot is the pivot, naturally
 @param angle is the angle of rotation cw in radians
 @returns the rotated point
 @since v0.99.1
 */
CGPoint ccpRotateByAngle(CGPoint v, CGPoint pivot, float angle);
```